# Access Azue Kubernetes services over private network

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

Am looking for a solution to make the AKS cluster as private, so that it can't be accessed over public ip. Below are the steps i followed and let me know for any other feasible solution

1. Created AKS cluster
2. Created nginx  controller with public ip load balancer
3. Created Private link service to the load balancer of nginx controller
4. Created private endpoint in another subscription to the PLS.

I want to access this nginx load balancer both via public ip and as well private ip endpoint. How can we have public/private DNS and how to access the private endpoint from on prem servers and as well from developer desktop.

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the CNI network type for the AKS, then all the pods have the private IP addresses in the VNet, in this way, you can access them through the private IP address. And you can also add the service with the load balancer type, then it will also be accessible outside with the public IP address.

Actually, the private endpoint is not for the Load Balancer, it's for the service such as the storage account, the database, and so on. If you want to access from another subscription. You can use the [VNet peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-peering-different-subscriptions), peer the two VNet, and then you can access the pods with the private IP address through another subscription.